# How to blink led on Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3, python-3, html5

I wrote python program that can be blink led on raspberry pi .

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO   ## Import GPIO library 
import time               ## import Delay library 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(26,GPIO.OUT)
while True:
     GPIO.output(26,True)  ##Turn on LED
     time.sleep(1)         ## wait for one second
     GPIO.output(26,False) ## Turn of LED
     time.sleep(1)
```

Now, I want to blink led with help of web page on apache server. So whenever I click on button, led should be blink.

HTML Page

```
<html>
<body>
<title>Raspberry PI</title>
<h1>LED</h1>
<form>
        <input type="Button" value="Blink LED" onclick="href='led.py'">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have just started to working on it. This is my effort, I have doubt on html Can you tell me, What's wrong in html page. How to blink led using web page?

Comment: Plenty of tutorials.  Find one, follow it, report a problem if you have one.

Comment: Yes there are so many example available on google. I have followed some tutorials.  I would like to follow method where I want make page using html and then I want to embedded python program into html page. As I was trying to do in question

Answer (score 0):

Just putting `"href='led.py'"` in your HTML isn't going to work - you need a web server that listens for requests from your web browser and then exectutes the code to blink the light.

Looking around online a bit I found [this article](http://www.knight-of-pi.org/cherrypy-an-elegant-python-webserver-for-raspberry-pi-remote-controls/) which shows how to blink an LED from a python web server, that might be a good starting point for you

Comment: I know how to setup server on Pi. My question is related to programming. I have asked what's the wrong in html program. I am sure there are something wrong. I couldn't embedded python program into html page. specially I have doubt in this line  <input type="Button" value="Blink LED" onclick="href='led.py'">

Comment: Basically HTML doesn't work like that, there is no way to execute a program on your pi directly from the HTML. That's why you need a web server - your browser sends a message to the server, and then the server runs your python code to blink the light. The browser itself isn't directly connected to your hardware.

Comment: I am totally agree with you but if you have a read my question carefully I have mention apache server in question and I know how does apache server work on PI. I have told you main problem in previous comment

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right, I misread your question. What you need is a way to make Apache execute the `led.py` script. As I said, just putting the script name in the HTML won't work. There are a few ways to do this, you could use CGI or a PHP extension, but I still think your best bet is going to be replacing Apache with a Python web server like in the article I linked to, then you can just call the code directly. You also want to make a specific url like `/blink` that will execute the code instead of serving HTML. Then you can use javascript to hit that URL when you press the button.